# How do C functions (like memcpy) deal with void* arrays, since you cannot do arithmetics on void pointers?

Tags: c

I was searching for solutions to implement a basic template function in C and worked out a half solution with macros in which you pass the type literal of the array, and that's because the generic list_t struct has "void* data" as an attribute, and you can't do arithmetic with void* so you have to cast it.
And now I'm interested in knowing how the C language itself deals with generic functions to manipulate void* arrays. Any idea?

Comment: You have your answer in the question itself - "you have to cast it".

Comment: For memcpy (and many other functions), it is sufficient to treat the address as a `char *`.  For user functions (eg. the target of a `qsort`), the writer of the function must either make assumptions about the object pointed to by the pointer (eg, the function writer treats the `void *` as a `struct foo *`), or the size of the object is embedded in a recognized location in the struct (eg, the first 4 bytes of the referenced object contain its size, or the data begins with a serialization of a data structure, or the function takes another parameter specifying the size, or ??).

Comment: @anatolyg: You have to convert it (explicitly or implicitly). You do not have to cast it.

Comment: Notably, C standard functions like `memcpy` may be implemented in ways that aren't standard compliant. It's almost certainly not implemented in strictly conforming C. So it's not meaningful to compare application code with `memcpy`'s internal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> the generic list_t struct has "void* data" as attribute, and you can't do arithmetic with void* so you have to cast it.

Actually, as regards the member itself inside the `list_t` structure, the size of the pointer itself is well known, so nothing prevents the language from indexing the list.

When however you want to access what is pointed by `data`, you indeed have to cast it to desired type, but it's a different operation.

Also, because of this, C won't emit a warning if you copy the content of a `void *` from or to a pointer of any type (he will do, however, when both pointers are non-void).

Comment: Re “C won't emit a warning if you copy the content of a void * from or to a pointer of any type”: Except pointers to function types are separate from pointers to object types, so conversions between them do elicit warnings, as in `void (*foo(void *p))(void) { return p; }`.